# .NET 6 Lambda Cold Start

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, .net-6.0, cold-start

i have a .net 6 serverless api running on aws lambda, and the cold start times for this endpoint:

```
endpoints.MapGet("/",
            async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Welcome to running ASP.NET Core on AWS Lambda");
            });
```

is from 5-8 seconds, but running it warm is only 90 ms..

what i dont understand is that the initialization time is only 700ms, but the invocation time is always over 5 seconds.
here is the logs for the cold start:
[cold start logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb0Ux.png)
warm logs:
[warm start logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmNAo.png)

there's clearly something that runs after my startup.cs class, but before my custom auth is started, during a cold start that's taking up a lot of time, but i cant figure out what. do i just have to make it where it has no cold starts, or can i fix the coldstart time?? i really dont understand what's happening here any help is appreciated.

[more logs insights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCpLn.png)

Comment: Please upload the code instead of pictures of it https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: III  changed  it .

Comment: A) please replace your images with the textual representation and B) please share your full function code. With 5 lines of code, nothing is debuggable. 'Custom auth' - `startup.cs` - there's a lot at play here.